# Discrete Frequency Equation and Relation

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, sampling

I think I am looking at conflicting equations from a few sources, or maybe I just dont understand it.

- $  \Omega $ is Discrete frequency
- $  N $ is Discrete Period in number of samples
- $  \omega $ is Continuous frequency
- $  T $ is Continuous time period
- $  F_{s} $ is Sampling frequency
- $  T_{s} = n $ is Sampling Time Instant
- $  k $ is Discrete harmonic index which goes from 0 to N/2 for a real signal

First equation forms I have seen
$$
\Omega = 2\pi f/F_{s} =\omega / F_{s} = \omega T_{s} = \omega n = 2\pi n / T  
$$
Second equation I have seen
$$
\Omega N = 2\pi k
$$
$$
\Omega  = 2\pi k / N
$$
Third equation I have seen
$$
\Omega_{k} = k F_{s} / N
$$

First and second look the same with if $k=T_{s} $ and if $N=T$ and first and third seem contrary.

Can someone explain please? 
Also if you can point in in a direction where all this is neatly derived and defined?

Thanks

Comment: Since you're using $\LaTeX$ so nicely, may I suggest sticking more to the de facto convention we get from *Oppenheim and Schafer*?  There, $\Omega=2 \pi f$ is continuous angular frequency in the continuous-time domain. $f_\mathrm{s}=\frac{1}{T}$ is the sample rate.  $\omega$ is continuous (but periodic) angular frequency in the discrete-time domain (the DTFT) and $\omega_k = 2 \pi \frac{k}{N}$ is discrete frequency (as in the DFT).  Normally the relationship of angular frequencies of the continuous-time and discrete-time domains is $\omega = \Omega T$.  $N$ is the size of data in the DFT.

Comment: I am looking for how they related in terms of equations above?